# Using $(tag).load() successfully in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to use jQuery to load an html document into an existing html document.

I've tried using the code below, but the text doesn't load.

I'm not sure why. Could someone point me towards what I'm doing wrong please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$("#test").load("test.txt")</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try on `DOM ready` like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#test").load("test.txt");
   });
</script>
```

And you also forgotted ending `;`.You can also try like

```
$(function(){
     $("#test").load("test.txt");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add it in dom ready

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#test").load("test.txt")
})
```

The problem was when your script is executed the element with id `test` was not yes added to the dom so the selector `$("#test")` would return zero elements

Comment: Thanks @'Arun P Johny' This is perfect. I chose Gautam's because he came in slightly earlier. But both answers are great. Helpful and clear.